# Open a file and write some word then read it get nothing

Tags: file, go

The code is like this. I can run the code with no error.when reading file，can‘t get anything

```
    file,err := os.OpenFile("writeAt.txt",os.O_CREATE|os.O_APPEND|os.O_RDWR,777)
    if err != nil{
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(file)
    reader := bytes.NewReader([]byte("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\n"))
    _,err = reader.WriteTo(file)
    if err != nil{
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(file)
    reader = bytes.NewReader([]byte("bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb\n"))
    _,err = reader.WriteTo(file)
    if err != nil{
        panic(err)
    }
    writer := bufio.NewWriter(os.Stdout)
    n,err := writer.ReadFrom(file)
    if err != nil{
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println("n",n)
```

Comment: when I Close() the file and reopen it ,it can be readed................why......

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you open a file and write to it, the file pointer (that determines where reads and writes occur) is continuously incremented so the next write always writes to the end. There is no separate "read" and "write" pointer, there's a single pointer where reads and writes happen. After you write something, you have to "rewind" the pointer to the beginning if you want to read what you just wrote to the file.

This means that attempting to read after the writes will read nothing as the file pointer points to the end of the file. Closing and reopening the file positions the pointer to the beginning of the file, that's why you succeed reading it after reopening.

To read the written content without reopening, set the pointer to the beginning of the file using [`File.Seek()`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#File.Seek).

For example:

```
if _, err := file.Seek(0, io.SeekStart); err != nil {
    log.Printf("Failed to seek: %v", err)
}

// Now you can read content written to it previosly
```

Also one more important thing. Quoting from `File.Seek()`:

> The behavior of Seek on a file opened with O_APPEND is not specified.

Since you do open your file with `O_APPEND`, the above may or may not succeed. So do not use `O_APPEND` if you wish to re-read the written content. Or if you must use `O_APPEND`, then you must reopen the file.